# Migrating MultiSite to SSL: Media Library not updating

Tags: multisite, media-library, https

I'm trying to migrate our companies websites over to SSL. We have 6 websites in total, migrating the 5 regular websites worked without a hitch, however our Multi Site installation is causing some weird grief.

To perform my migration I have installed an SSL Certificate on the server, used this plugin ["Better Search Replace"](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)  to run through the database to update all urls from http:// to https:// site wide.

On the multisite, the media library urls are still reflecting http:// after running the search and replace, and are no longer visible on the frontend of the multisite.

I did the exact same procedure on my regular installs, and that worked without any problems. Does anybody have suggestions on how to get the media library in line?

UPDATE: I have updated all of my plugins / wordpress updates to their latest verisons. Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

When changing to SSL, be sure to edit your wp-admin > Settings > General > **Wordpress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** values to include `https`.

If still having troubles the media items (I believe) are built with `site_url` or `home` values (mentioned above) in `_options`. Verify they're `https`, then check out if you have a value in `upload_url_path`, if so verify its set to `https`.

If nether of those things work, within your database (presumably with phpmyadmin) check to see in `_posts` what the `guid` value is of a specific media item is (where `post_type` is `attachment`). If those are `http`, you can update them in to `https` with a script like:

```
UPDATE `_posts` SET `guid ` = replace(guid, 'http:', 'https:');
```

*(always back up your database before running a query like that!)*

When moving to SSL, its also recommend that on your Apache/Nginx server, you setup a redirect that forwards all `http` requests to `https` *before* the code is reach, this saves a lot of work and makes life a lot easier (there's thousands of how-to for that online).